# Create alarm on log system

Tags: logging, syslog

I want to set an "alarm" on my Ubuntu machine that reports weird stuff happening in my logs. Let's say I want it to save information when a certain event occurs, for example somebody attempted to log in and failed.
Any ideas?

Edit1: I know that there are tools like OSSEC, but I wanted to do it on my own, like setting a certain set of rules that would trigger my own alarm. I'm just playing around with the log systems, so I'm not quite sure what I want is possible.

Comment: You should look at intrusion detection systems such as OSSEC. Otherwise define "weird".

Comment: Oh I have installed that yet, but I was wondering if I could do it manually

Comment: I would say creating your own IDS is too broad a question for *any* Stack Exchange website, but you'd be better off asking at more specific questions at [security.se] or [sf].

Comment: @muru Ahh my mistake! Ta.

Comment: When you say "I wanted to do it on my own" what exactly do you mean?  If you're referring to writing your own scripts or program, then @muru is correct.  However, given the large number of tools already out there such as OSSEC HIDS I don't know why you'd do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fail2ban` is pretty much what you're describing.
You tell it what to watch and what to do if something is triggered.

It ships with a bunch of scripts that watch for `auth.log` abuses (which trigger iptables bans), amongst other things. I've even wired up a Wordpress site to trigger IP blocking if somebody tries to brute force the login page.

The syntax isn't completely obvious but it is flexible.